# azure-devops-node-api: How to setDocumentByName in ProjectCollection scope

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

How to set document in ProjectCollection scope?
I tries to call `setDocumentByName` method but `ScopeType` and `ScopeValue`parameters are requred.
When I tries to set empty strings for these parameters it doesn't work.

```js
import * as azdev from "azure-devops-node-api";
import extmgmtm = require("azure-devops-node-api/ExtensionManagementApi");

let authHandler = azdev.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token);
let connection = new azdev.WebApi(orgUrl, authHandler);

let api = await connection.getExtensionManagementApi();

  await api
    .setDocumentByName(
      {
        id: "key",
        value: inputString,
      },
      publisher,
      extensionName,
      "User",         //scopeType
      "Me",           //scopeValue
      "collection1"
    )
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

For `scopeType` we need to use `Default` instead of `User`
and `Current` for `scopeValue` instead of `Me`.

Comment: That's great you found the solution. You can accept above answer of yours